# Select statement failing after h2 database jar upgrade in oracle mode

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

After upgrading H2 database version from 1.3.171 to 1.4.187, my select statement failing with the jdbc error code [90022-187]. I'm, using Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.3.5.

Error Trace :

Function "BUS_ENTY_GUID" not found; SQL statement:
select * from ( select consumerin0_.CNSMR_INTNT_SID as CNSMR_IN1_0_0_, busentity1_.BUS_ENTY_SID as BUS_ENTY1_4_1_, intentuser2_.USR_SID as USR_SID1_10_2_ where consumerin0_.OWNR_ENTY_NM=busentity1_.BUS_ENTY_GUID(+) and consumerin0_.USR_EXTRNL_ID=intentuser2_.MAG_GUID(+) and lower(consumerin0_.ORD_ID)=lower(?) and lower(intentuser2_.USR_LAST_NM)=lower(?) ) where rownum <= ? [90022-187]

Kindly help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 no longer supports the "old style" Oracle outer join syntax. You will have to use "outer join" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Thomas for you help!

I was using org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect, hence conversion of the query has older style joins. Now I have changed it to Oracle10gDialect which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dh2.oldStyleOuterJoin=true` to support older syntax.

Visit http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/SysProperties.html